# What are all possible values of txreceipt_status?

Tags: ether, etherscan

I was wondering what are all the txreceipt_status possible statuses. I was investigating some blocks and noticed that some statuses are empty like: ' ' or have '1'. For both of those, transactions happened. So what is the difference between those, and what other status messages exist ?

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer.

From the code, in [`receipt.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/461291882edce0ac4a28f64c4e8725b7f57cbeae/core/types/receipt.go#L37), the only allowed values are `0` and `1`, denoting failure and success respectively.

```
const (
    // ReceiptStatusFailed is the status code of a transaction if execution failed.
    ReceiptStatusFailed = uint64(0)

    // ReceiptStatusSuccessful is the status code of a transaction if execution succeeded.
    ReceiptStatusSuccessful = uint64(1)
)
```

I'm assuming that the empty case, `' '`, equates to failure. (Though I can't immediately back up this assertion with anything specific in the code.)

Comment: This field was added around 10/16/2017 to etherscan and tx before that have an empty `txreceipt_status`

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing that up! :-)

Comment: Seems that internal tx has it empty too `0xb9cb4609ed1f541ae76a7987e71b4b970af9080b90f685c2343c75d6d8c35481`, that one is from 2019